# Insert values in SQLite one row at a time

Tags: python, database, sqlite

For every loop in the code below, the INSERT INTO inserts the assigned value to the correct column BUT in a new row:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('testtable.sqlite3')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.executescript(''' DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tracks;
                      CREATE TABLE Tracks (id, singer, song)''')

lst = ['id', 'singer', 'song']

for i in range(len(lst)):
    print 'Enter a value for column', lst[i]
    insdata = raw_input('>>> ')
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Tracks ({col}) VALUES (?)'''\
    .format(col=lst[i]), (insdata, ))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

**Question**: How can I tell SQLite *not to* change row in each loop and populate the table one row at a time?

**Notice**: I don't want to explicitly refer to all columns names in my code (like, INSERT INTO Table (all columns)) because in my practice script I have the user to input their name and total number.

Comment: You can't insert "a part of" a row in any RDBMS; you'll need to generate the appropriate parameters list and query parameters. Also beware SQL injection in the column names, and unless you're working on something schema-independent, a dynamically altered schema is usually the wrong solution.

Comment: I'm just practicing for myself, trying some staff, applying new concepts. I don't really get the first part of your reply. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the database within the loop. Instead, use the loop to fill a data structure (list, dictionary...) with everything you want to go in the new row. Then, after the loop, use that data structure to build the `INSERT...` clause with all the data.

In case it is not clear: you can't tell SQLite to `INSERT ...` without creating a new row. `INSERT` always creates a new row.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, most probably I had to be more clear. I came up with a working solution below.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully, it was doable. I reply to myself for future reference and to keep the initial code above, for comparison. I comment what I did and how I came up with an answer to my problem inside the code. Feeling sad though for having been downvoted for describing a problem that actually could be solved using the following trick...

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('testdb.sqlite3')
cur = conn.cursor()

lst = ['id', 'singer', 'song'] # let's assume that through prompts, user has 
                               # previously added these values and the
                               # script put them in this list.

cur.executescript('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Tracks;
                     CREATE TABLE Tracks (id, singer, song)''')
conn.commit()

def populate_tb():
    print 'Insert  value for column: ', lst[0] 
    inp = raw_input('>>> ') # user types the value for the first column (in 
                            # this example, id column)
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Tracks ({col}) VALUES (?)'\
.format(col=lst[0]), (inp,))
                       # the value is inserted to id column.
    conn.commit()
    if len(lst)-1 > 1: # meaning, continue iff user created a table with 
                       # more than one column. I subtract one because lst[0] 
                       # item has already been assigned a value above with 
                       # the INSERT.
        for i in range(len(lst)-1): # I run a loop for the remaining list 
                                    # items (singer, song columns)
            print 'Insert value for column: ', lst[i+1]
            inps = raw_input('>>> ')
            cur.execute('UPDATE Tracks SET {col} = (?) WHERE id = (?)'\
.format(col=lst[i+1]), (inps,inp))
            # And here is the solution. I just UPDATE the newly created row so 
            # I get what I want: user is prompted to populate a table, 'cell 
            # by cell', horizontally, without changing line as it was 
            # happening with my initial code in the top. Instead of 
            # declaring explicitly which columns to populate (which is 
            # impossible in my scenario since the user is prompted 
            # dynamically to create the columns), I use only one column 
            # reference which varies according to the loop counter that 
            # traverses list's items.
            conn.commit()

populate_tb()
```

So my initial **question** (given our context): *How can I tell SQLite not to change row in each loop and populate the table one row at a time?* is **answered**: *You can 'tell' SQLite that you're inserting just the first value and then you UPDATE the rest of the empty cells in this row.*

Comment: With this approach if the program crashes in the middle for whatever reason you end up with a semi-populated row with some (or many) empty fields, which might or might not be what you want. Using only one INSERT is an atomic operation, you either have the row inserted with all the specified fields or nothing at all. Usually people prefer the latter, that's why so much effort is put into making SQL operations atomic and things like transactions exist.